# Integrate prestashop database with local database

Tags: php, python, mysql, database, prestashop

I was looking around and couldn't find an answer for this question. If however, it is duplicated in some way, I apologise.

My problem is: I have a physical store, which has a accounting program with some database where my products are. I now created a store with prestashop and wanted to synchronise both of them.

I want to be able to add a REF to my prestashop and take every field from my LOCAL DB (except images and descriptions); I also want to synchronise the STOCKS in "real time".

My idea is having a "middle DB" which takes requests and updates the other 2 DB, as such:
**Prestashop DB <-> MIDDLE DB <-> Local DB**

My middle DB would have the REFs and Quantities for all the products and check if the latter field is changed in either DB, let's say every 2 mins, to then update the database that did NOT perform the request.

How difficult is it to do this? How can I connect to both databases, using python, c# or c++ and perform such tasks?
I'm using prestashop 1.6.  and I have access to my database via PHPmyAdmin.

Thank you!

Comment: In my opinion you should consider using a build-in PrestaShop API and just create integration, you can use Python, c# or c++ to create application for an API using WebService, right? :)

Comment: What database is this? Does it have replication features?

Comment: @krystian - it's a DB that contes with the accounting program: most fields exists, and the others I can fill by hand and just not include it in the synchroniser script. I was looking into webService for prestashop but all the examples and documentation is about customers, nothing about the products. Could I use it in the same way? Do you have any example?

Comment: ALSO, isn't it safer to have a middle DB to prevent both DB to write at the same time? Let's say that a customer buys product X online and another buys the same product at the same time on physical store.. when synchronising, there'd be no diff, but in reality we should take 2 products from both DB... No?

Comment: Sure you can use webservice for products, customers, orders, categories, everything related to PrestaShop, i don't think that it would be safer... if someone buys the product in physical store it should inform local database, if something have changed in local database webservice request should be triggered to update stocks in PrestaShop database.

This is how it works for a few of my customers. They all use integration via webservice.

Comment: Ok, thank you :) the only reason I thought you could have a middle DB is in case both DB try to write on each other at the same time. But really, the probability of that happening is very low. Do you have any example of a connector working? I'm sorry in advance if I'm asking too much